# Getting by name values from rows that are returned under "inner join" in SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, .net

I'm using some stored procedures in an ASP.Net page. I often use either the row number or the name of the row between quotes, but I can't find a way to access inner-joined tables by name:

```
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection("my_connection_string")
    Dim mycommand As New SqlCommand("last_played_songs", conn)
    mycommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", userid)
    conn.Open()
    Dim dr As SqlDataReader = mycommand.ExecuteReader()
    While dr.Read()

        /* What I have: */
        Dim artist_image As String = dr(39) & "" & "/cover.jpg"      

        /* What I want. Let's say I called my table ArtistProfile under inner join: */
        Dim artist_image As String = dr("ArtistProfile.uniqueID") & "/cover.jpg"

   End While
```

It seems that using the name used with inner join is not the good syntax, but I can't find how to name it in order to be able to access 'inner-joined' tables. The problem with numeric index is that if one of the 4-5 joined tables structure change, all indexes are changing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alias the field names in the stored procedure to get this desired output

```
select 
  TableA.Name as 'TableA.Name',
  TableA.Age as 'TableA.Age',
  TableB.Address as 'TableB.Address'
from
  TableA INNER JOIN TableB ON TableA.ID = TableB.ID

-- Example using table alias in SQL
select 
  a.Name as 'TableA.Name',
  a.Age as 'TableA.Age',
  b.Address as 'TableB.Address'
from
  TableA a INNER JOIN TableB b ON a.ID = b.ID
```

The default name of the column is the fieldname itself, so in your example it should be just dr("uniqueID")

Comment: So, instead of naming my tables during inner join, I alias them in the select? Also, all my tables contain a "uid" field, so most of the time, I need to call it explicitely, by the 'full path', thus my question about the naming convention to fetch from a specific table in ASP.Net.

Comment: the alias on the tables in the join clause makes it easier to read the select clause.  This table alias is never exposed in the result.  The column names will only ever be the field name unless you alias.